# Passing values to generic list from one Blazor component to another

Tags: c#, blazor

I have two variables within a generic list called `RowData` and it has 2 variables called `RowPosition` and `RowInfo` that would given data on the server side.

The generic list would be imported into a function that would build the form and use the data passed to it.

My question is what do I use on the server side to allow the data be passed? For example:

```
RowPosition : RowInfo
1 : blahyes
2 : blahno
3 : blahlol
4 : blahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post enough code for me to have much to go on as far as suggestions, but there are a few ways for components to talk to each other.

You can use a Cascading Value, and child components will be able to refer to the parent like this:

```
<CascadingValue Value="GalleryManager">
    <ArtistListViewer></ArtistListViewer>
    <ImageListViewer></ImageListViewer>
</CascadingValue>
```

Here my ArtistListViewer and ImageListViewer components can refer to the Gallery Manager with this property:

```
[CascadingParameter]
GalleryManager GalleryManager { get; set; }
```

If used too often this can lead to performance issues, depending on how busy your site is.

I wrote a blog post about another way:

Using Interfaces To Communicate Between Components
https://datajugglerblazor.blogspot.com/2020/01/how-to-use-interfaces-to-communicate.html

If you send anything complex, I prefer the method above where a parent object is a IBlazorComponentParent, and a child object is an IBlazorComponent.

Nuget Package: DataJuggler.Blazor.Components

Here is the way you can setup Parent property on the child like this:

```
 <Login OnLogin="LoginComplete" Parent=this></Login>
```

The Parent=this is possible because my Login component is an IBlazorComponent, and my Index page is an IBlazorComponentParent.

The child setter registers with the Parent like this:

```
public IBlazorComponentParent Parent
{
    get { return parent; }
    set 
    { 
        // set the parent
        parent = value;

        // if the value for HasParent is true
        if (HasParent)
        {
            // Register with the parent to receive messages from the parent
            Parent.Register(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The Register event on the Index page stores the child as a property:

```
public void Register(IBlazorComponent component)
{
    // If the component object exists
    if (NullHelper.Exists(component, Children))
    {
        // If this is the Login component
        if (component.Name == "Login")
        {
            // Set the Signup control
            this.Login = component as Login;
        }

        // add this child
        Children.Add(component);
    }
}
```

At this point, my Login component knows about its parent, and the parent Index page has the Login component as a variable.

Then you can send a message with anything you like.

In my login complete method, I send a message to the parent:

```
// if the Parent exists
if (HasParent)
{
    // create a message to send
    Message message = new Message();

    // Set the text
    message.Text = loginResponse.Message;

    // Send a message to the parent
    Parent.ReceiveData(message);;
}
```

I am just passing in text above, but there is also a NamedParameters collection that you can pass any type of data (object).

There is a full working example and tutorial here if interested:

Code
https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorImageGallery

Video
https://youtu.be/3xKXJQ4qThQ